# JSF page is losing CSS styles in the master template when clicked on submit

Tags: jsf, commandbutton

I am new to the StackOverflow , though I've been following it for quite a while. 
The issue is :
I have a JSF page like a confirmation page where the users land from a different page. Now the confirmation page contains a whole lot of templates(which have some header and footer tiles and CSS,JS), which show up very well when I land there.

There is a form in the confirmation page with couple of attributes to submit .And when there is an error and I click on submit , all the templates are lost and I just get the /faces/confPage.xhtml with the error message.

Below is my code and result:

`

```
  <h:form id="configForm" >

     ------
     ------
             <h:commandButton type="submit" id="xxxButton" value="Click here to           
                 Apply Changes" action="#{xxxBean.saveDataListTest}"          
                styleClass="applybutton" >

             </h:commandButton>
          </div>

     </h:form>
```

`

This is just a section of the xhtml I have shown. My regular url to which all the pages point to is localhost:7001/XXX_GUI/faces/ , and this is when the styles display property with all templates. BUt when I hit submit and if there are errors on the page, the url goes : localhost:7001/XXX_GUI/faces/configPage.xhtml instead of the former.

FYI - I have used  in the faces-config.xml for the outcome. But looks like when there is an error on the page , the Navigation rules are not called at all.

Excuse my wording and format as this is my first post.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show how you're including CSS resources in the page/template.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, here you go :                                        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="default.css" />
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="dashboard.css" />
 <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="homepage.css" />

Comment: Okay, it will autogenerate the right URLs, so that's likely not the problem (apart from an [improper usage of `library` attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used), but that's a different problem). Well, do you have any filters configured in the webapp? Have you looked at the HTTP traffic monitor in webbrowser's developer toolset? Press F12 in Chrome/IE9/Firebug and look at *Net(work)* tab. What exactly did the browser retrieve while attempting to download those CSS resources?

Comment: Yes I do have the SpringSecurityFilterChain configured, but I changed all the filter attributes to "none" . Yeah I looked at the Net tab in Firebug, as soon as I hit Submit , only the localhost:7001/XXX_GUI/faces/configPage.xhtml is seen and no other css or js .     Also there were supposed to be certain href links on the left Side of the page which are added  from earlier actions , and even they do not appear.